# jQuery - Start animation automatically when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created this site on webflow: https://flumes-fantastic-site.webflow.io/ with the help of the jquery ripples library and I'm trying to make the automatic drops start when I load the page, as of now, I have to go to another tab and come back to it so it can start playing.

I'm new to coding so I'm probably messing up here with the code. This is what a friend from the stackoverflow (Daniels118) helped me piece together:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.ripples@0.6.3/dist/jquery.ripples.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#ripple').ripples({
    resolution: 512,
    dropRadius: 30,
    perturbance: 0.04,
});


function randomDrop() {
  var $el = $('#ripple');
    var x = Math.random() * $el.outerWidth();
    var y = Math.random() * $el.outerHeight();
    var dropRadius = 30;
    var strength = 0.04 + Math.random() * 0.04;
    $el.ripples('drop', x, y, dropRadius, strength);
}

$(function() {
  $("#ripple").focus();
});

$(function() {
        $('#ripple').ripples({
        resolution: 512,
    dropRadius: 30,
    perturbance: 0.04
  });
  var timer = null;
  $(window).focus(function() {
    if (timer === null) {
      //console.log('on');
      timer = setInterval(randomDrop, 1000);
    }
  })
  .blur(function() {
    if (timer !== null) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;
      //console.log('off');
    }
  })
  .focus();
});

</script>
```

I appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've set the interval which causes the random drops to only start when the `window.focus()` event fires. Instead, just create this interval directly within `document.ready`.

In addition, you can improve the raindrop effect by using a recursive `setTimeout()`, with a random delay between instances, instead of a fixed `setInterval()`. Finally, that you've got some repeated code which can be removed.

With that said, try this:

```js
let randomDrop = $el => {
  var x = Math.random() * $el.outerWidth();
  var y = Math.random() * $el.outerHeight();
  var dropRadius = 30;
  var strength = 0.04 + Math.random() * 0.04;
  $el.ripples('drop', x, y, dropRadius, strength);
}

let setRandomInterval = (callback, minInterval, maxInterval) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
    setRandomInterval(callback, minInterval, maxInterval);      
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxInterval - minInterval + 1) + minInterval));
}

$(function() {
  let $el = $('#ripple').ripples({
    resolution: 512,
    dropRadius: 30,
    perturbance: 0.04
  });
  
  setRandomInterval(() => randomDrop($el), 500, 3000);
});
```

```css
#ripple {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/KHIuHuH.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.ripples@0.6.3/dist/jquery.ripples.min.js"></script>

<div id="ripple" class="jquery-ripples"></div>
```

Comment: Rory, you're the man. Major thanks to you!

Comment: There is one problem though, this solutions brings back the first problem I was having as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73307918/how-to-pause-jquery-animation-when-window-is-not-in-focus/73308989#73308989 which would cause the drops to load when in another tab and shoot them all at once when I changed back to it. Any way we can integrate both of these solutions? Automatic start of drops and halt them when not 'focused'?